# STEP 1 2016 geometry question, is this argument reversible?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

From the University of Cambridge's entrance exams:
[image]

For the final part of this question, the official mark scheme gives 9 marks (almost half of the entire question's credit) and gives an algebraic proof. My question is, why can't we simply argue that the entire argument is reversible?

My working basically looked the same as theirs:

[image]

It's clear that at each stage the number we're squaring is positive and so it's clear that when we take roots for the reverse argument they're all going to be positive, so there's no ambiguity. (Perhaps "clear" is a stretch, but readily explainable).

I wondered, because the final part asks about new, potentially different numbers, is that the reason why a whole new argument is necessary? But I can't see why that would be so, because the first relation holds *iff* the lengths are the radii of touching circles, and then that holds *iff* the second relation holds, so all the statements are equivalent, and the "new" numbers fall within the generality of the original radii lengths.

Please note that I'm not asking a question about the way exams are marked, but a question about the way maths is done properly!

Comment: "It's clear that at each stage the number we're squaring is positive"  I don't quite see it for $(1/b - 1/a - 1/ c)$

Comment: So, like you are alluding to, what you need to show that we need to take the "positive" square root. In particular, show that 1/  $ - 1/\sqrt{b} \neq 1/\sqrt{c} + 1/\sqrt{a}$ (obvious, uses $a,b, c, >0$) and 2/ $ 1/b-1/a-1/a \neq - 2/\sqrt{ac}$ (requires some work, uses $ b < c < a$.), so that we can reject the "negative" square root.

Answer (score 1):

(ii)
For simplicity, let us denote $x=1/b, y=1/c \; \text{and} \; z=1/a.$
Then $x>y>z>0,$ and $(**)$ reads $$2(z^2+x^2+y^2)=(z+x+y)^2.$$
"Official solution" is reversible until
$$(x-y-z)^2=4yz.$$ From this
$$ \sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}\pm \sqrt{z}.$$
However, as $$\sqrt{x}> \sqrt{y}> \sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z},$$ only $ \sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}+ \sqrt{z}$ can occur.